# Consistency of sample correlations from CCA

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, inference, multivariate-analysis, biostatistics

I want to prove a consistency of the sample correlations from canonical correlation analysis(CCA). Here is an informal statement of the theorem: Let $\textbf{X}$ and $\textbf{Y}$ be two p-dimensional and q-dimensional random vectors, respectively, with joint distribution P. Let $\left( x_{1},y_{1} \right), \ldots,(x_{n},y_{n})$ be random samples from P. Suppose $\textbf{r}$ be a set of population correlations between canonical variates produced when doing CCA between $\textbf{X}$ and $\textbf{Y}$. Note that the length of $\textbf{r}$, $|\textbf{r}|=\min(p,q)$. We use population covariance matrices to calculate $\textbf{r}$. In data analysis, we replace the population covariance matrix with the sample covariance matrix which results in sample correlations, $\hat{\textbf{r}}$. Then, $\hat{\textbf{r}}_{n}$ converges to $\textbf{r}$ in probability as n goes to infinity. I really appreciate any help.

Comment: I think you need to be more clear about what you are asking. What do you mean by *the canonical correlation* between **X** and **Y**. The first canonical correlation? The whole set?  Also $r=\min(p,q)$ is just an integer measuring dimensions, not a correlation value.

Comment: @ThomasLumley Thank you for the comment. I edited the question. I hope it is more clear now.